# Can't execlp netcat

Tags: c, exec, netcat

I'm trying to exec the following command from C:

`netcat 127.0.0.1 4444`

This is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    execlp("/usr/bin/netcat", "127.0.0.1", "4444", 0);
}
```

However, I keep getting the error: **Error: no ports specified for connection**.

To answer a few questions I feel may come up:

- `which netcat` gives `/usr/bin/netcat`
- I've tried using `execvp` and got the same results
- Running the command normally, i.e. via a terminal, is successful (Usually i also give the `-e /bin/bash` argument but I've omitted it for simplicity.  Adding it doesn't change the results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your first argument is "4444". Why?

Look at this line:

```
execlp("/usr/bin/netcat", "127.0.0.1", "4444", 0);
```

The *first* argument to `execlp()` is the binary to execute. The rest of the arguments will form the `argv[]`-vector passed to the process.

By convention, `argv[0]` should contain the name of the executable and the first "real" argument is `argv[1]`, which is "4444" in your case. So what you do is the equivalent on the shell of

> netcat 4444

and the correct call would be:

```
execlp("/usr/bin/netcat", "netcat", "127.0.0.1", "4444", 0);
```

Btw. the use of `execlp()` makes only sense when calling a binary without a full path, since it looks for the correct path itself (using the PATH environment variable). Otherwise, `execl()` should be used. But it will work anyway.

Comment: Yep, I'm dumb and I completely forgot about that.  Thanks!